# Reduce Subset-Sum to Sat

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, satisfiability, subset-sum, polynomial-time-reductions

Is there a reduction from SUBSET-SUM to SAT?
Just general SAT, not 3-SAT.
Also the given multiset S only has positive integers.

SUBSET-SUM is defined as follows:
Input: a multiset S = { x1 , ... , xn } of positive integers and a positive integer t
Output:
accept if there exists a sub-multiset { y1, …, ym } ⊆ S such that y1 + ··· + ym = t
reject otherwise

x1 , ... , xn and t are encoded in binary notation.

The boolean formula SUM should be used in the reduction.

Let a1···ak, b1···bk, c1···ck be k-bit integers.

SUM(a1, ... , ak, b1, ... , bk, c1, ... , ck) is true iff (a1···ak) + (b1···bk) = c1···ck

For example, if k = 3, sum(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1) is true because 011 + 100 = 111.

Can this be done?

For example, what would the boolean formula produced by the reduction look like for
S = { 010, 011, 011, 100 }
t = 110

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reduce subset sum to 3SAT](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111692/reduce-subset-sum-to-3sat)

Answer (score 2):

I think a direct reduction can be done by the following process:
setup a enable gate $e_i$ for each integer $x_i$ (then we can represent each bit of $x_i$ using $e_i$ and $0$), add all integers (with enable gate) up using adder circuits, then compare the overall sum with goal $t$. Here we obtained a circuit with $n$ inputs $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n$, and its output is the truth value of $t = \sum_{e_i = 1} x_i$, which is a CIRCUIT-SAT problem. Moreover we can convert this circuit to FORMULA-SAT, which is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cook-Levin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem) demonstrates a reduction from SUBSET-SUM to SAT.

If you wanted a reduction from SAT to SUBSET-SUM, then yes, such a reduction exists; SUBSET-SUM is NP-complete, and thus the existence of such a reduction follows from [the definition of NP-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness#Formal_definition).  You should be able to take any standard proof of NP-completeness for SUBSET-SUM and chain the reductions together to get the desired reduction.

Comment: Thanks. So I do mean subset-sum to sat, not the other way around. Also I'm looking for a direct reduction, not the one implied by the cook levin theorem, and one that uses the sum function i mentioned.

Comment: @Amy, ok, can you edit your question to reflect what you want to ask?  Right now the headline question asks whether there is a reduction.  I suggest you also tell us about what methods you already know of that you've rejected and why you rejected them.